# Java SWT: Label width not changing after changing it's text

Tags: java, eclipse, label, swt, windowbuilder

I read a lot about this problem here in Stack Overflow and applied all the proposed solutions (getShell pack, layout, getparent layout etc...) and none of them worked.

I have a label with a text value. Also I have a button and when click on that button I'm changing the content of the label with a longer text. The problem is that the width of the label doesn't change and only a part of the new longer text is visible.

My text code:

```
Composite composite_2 = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
composite_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1, 1));
composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label lblNumbers = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
lblNumbers.setText("Números:");

Label lblNumbersValue = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);   
lblNumbersValue.setText("...");
```

.
.
.

```
btnElegirNmeros.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        lblNumbersValue.setText("asddadadasdasdasd");
        lblNumbersValue.getParent().layout();
        lblNumbersValue.pack();
        getShell().pack();
        getShell().layout();
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, could you provide a [mcve] ? If everything is setup correctly it should be enough to do `lblNumbersValue.requestLayout();`.

Comment: it worked! @LorisSecuro please post it as an asnwer and i will accept it. requestLayout solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SWT 4.6, the most reliable method to trigger a layout update is [`Control.requestLayout()`](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#requestLayout--).

It should solve these kind of problems.

So in your case try `lblNumbersValue.requestLayout();`.